# Fibonacci Assembly with Loop Stack Iteration

Tags: loops, assembly, stack, mips, fibonacci

I am trying to write the fibonacci function in a loop in assembly language, but I cannot find the values I find in a certain order and add them to my stack.

The user will ask for the stack sequence range from us and the loop should be in the form of the equation `For n> 1 F (n) = F (n-1) + F (n-2)`.

I could not understand what is my fault.

Example program should be like that; Enter the sequence number: 6, F(6) = 8

```
.data
str: .asciiz "Enter the sequence number: \n"
f:  .word 0,1
.text
main:
la $s0 f        #address of f
lw $s1 0($s0)       
addi $a0 $zero 0    #int a0 = f[0]:0(s1) 
lw $s2 4($s0)       
addi $a1 $zero 1    #int a1 = f[1]:1(s2)

li $v0 4
la $a0 str      #print string
syscall

li $v0 5        
syscall
move $t0 $v0        #read integer t0=n
jal FIBO

addi $t1 $v0 0      #t1=v0=sum
add $t2 $a0 $a1     #t2=a0+a1=f[0]+f[1];
add $t3 $t2 $t1     #t3=t1+t2

li $v0 1        #print(t3)
addi $a0 $t3 0

li $v0 10       #exit program
syscall

FIBO:

addi $t1 $zero 1    #constant 1
addi $t2 $t0 0      #i:t2=n:t0
addi $t3 $zero 0    #f(i)=0:sum:t3;

#f(n)
#for (i=n, i>1, i--)
#   f(i):sum = f(i-1)+f(i-2);
#return f(i)
FIBOLOOP:
slt $t4 $t1 $t2     #t1:1<t2:i
beq $t4 $zero EXIT_LOOP
addi $t4 $t2 -1
addi $t5 $t2 -2
add $t3 $t4 $t5
sub $sp $sp -24
sw $t3 0($sp)       #BACKUP-STORING t3----1 
sw $t3 4($sp)   
sw $t3 8($sp)   
sw $t3 12($sp)
sw $t3 16($sp)
sw $t3 20($sp)          
subi $t2 $t2 1      # i--: we could write "addi t2 t2 -1" too
j FIBOLOOP

EXIT_LOOP:
add $sp $sp 24      #RESTORE t3---------2
lw $t3 0($sp)
lw $t3 4($sp)
lw $t3 8($sp)
lw $t3 12($sp)
lw $t3 16($sp)
lw $t3 20($sp)
addi $t4 $t3 0
move $v0 $t4
jr $ra
```

Comment: You don't need any stack space for Fibonacci, just `x +=y` and swap x and y.  (Or unroll by 2 and do `x += y; y+=x;`

Comment: Thank you, this equation worked for me and I saw my fault.